# Make [PyPDF2] a synonym of [pypdf]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

### Proposal

- Replace the tag [pypdf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypdf2) by [pypdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypdf)
- Make [pypdf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypdf2) (1001 questions) a synonym of [pypdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypdf) (279 questions).

### Historic background

- pyPdf is the original project. It was developed from 2005 - 2010. It didn't receive updates from 2010 - December 2022.
- PyPDF2 was developed from 2011 - 2016. It didn't receive updates from 2016-2022. I (Martin Thoma) became the maintainer in April 2022. A few months later I also became the maintainer of pypdf.
- In December 2022 I released [PyPDF2==3.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/3.0.0/) and [pypdf==3.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/). Both versions are essentially the same, just

Proof that I'm the maintainer:

- [pypdf on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/): Look at the side-bar on the left side
- [PyPDF2 on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf2/): Look at the side-bar on the left side
- [Linked documentation of pypdf](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/history.html): This is linked on PyPI. In [the contributors section](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/CONTRIBUTORS.html) you can see a link to my Stackoverflow profile
- [Linked documentation of PyPDF2](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/history.html): This is essentially the same as the docs above.

My plans:

- `pypdf` will get active development
- `PyPDF2` will only receive critical bugfixes (and likely also only if somebody makes a good PR / if the fix is rather small). I will leave it as-is on PyPI so that people who version-pinned it can keep using it.

The [migration from PyPDF2==1.x to PyPDF2==2.x](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/migration-1-to-2.html) is mainly renaming some classes / methods. The main differentce to PyPDF2==3.x is that DeprecationWarnings were changed to Exceptions.

Here are some indications on how much work the various version upgrades are for users:

- Much: `pypdf==1.x` → `PyPDF2==2.x` / `PyPDF2==3.x`
- Very Little: `pypdf==1.x` → `PyPDF2==1.x`
- Very Little: `PyPDF2==2.x` → `PyPDF2==3.x`
- Very Little: `PyPDF2==3.x` → `pypdf==3.x`

### Reasons for the switch

1. The two projects are one again
2. Users regularly confused the two tags already. [Many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypdf+pypdf2) have both tags already, although I tried to ensure they are used distinct before.

Comment: @Zoe Shouldn't I receive the https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1224/synonymizer badge for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The badge is only awarded if you propose the synonym that gets voted to approval (by other users or a mod) via the on-site synonym system (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pypdf/synonyms in this case). However, that wouldn't have worked in this case anyway, because pypdf had so many fewer questions than pypdf2, that the system only allows mods to make a synonym in the direction you wanted (and requiring a merge to do so, which only mods can do). Mods also can't hand out badges manually, so we can't be the manual link between the badge and the unautomateable meta posts

Comment: Thank you for explaining :-)